# how do i get a brother MFC-8860DN to work over network

Tags: printing

I have looked at the brother website. They have instructions but Im not sure which applies. I called them. They say they don't support linux.

Answer (score 0):

So far all the Brother printers (as well as most of the printers I have dealt with) has been recognized by using the Add Printer from System Settings.  On the other occasions I have found drivers either provided by the Manufacture or generic drivers provided by the Linux community.

In this case Linux Drivers is provided by the manufacturer.

Look at [MCF-8860DN - Linux Drivers](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=as_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc8860dn_all&os=128) provided by Brother.

By the way, I also experience the similar as you when trying for support VIA phone.  The people answering the phone usually say they don't support linux.